# In-page navigation or Site navigation?

Tags: html

What is the best approach for creating a website with multiple page navigation. I've done both in the past but i dont know with one is better.

**In-page navigation:**

```
<nav>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#products">Products</a>
  <a href="#about">About Us</a>
</nav>
<div id="home">
  ...
</div>
<div id="products">
  ...
</div>
<div id="about">
  ...
</div>
```

You can have multiple divs and hide them and show them using css when each link is active.

**Site navigation:**

```
<nav>
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="products.html">Products</a>
  <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
</nav>
```

You have multiple html files and you just redirect to them.

I think the most common way to do it is the second way, but if you dont use a server side code processor/compiler/library you will need to duplicate the layout(is this example just the nav but can be more).

Which one should i use for a simple website, different sections or different pages?

Comment: It depends what you need of of site.

Comment: Can you extend more? In which case is better one or another?